# Who are the Legendary Seven?

Tags: neptunia-v

In *Hyperdimension Neptunia V* there are seven legendary heroes based on famous game developers.

[image: screenshot with seven silhouettes]

I'm fairly sure the first three are Toshiyuki Takahashi, Yuji Horii, and Hironobu Sakaguchi, and the sixth is Shigeru Miyamoto. Who are the other three?

Comment: This page *might* help, as it lists some references: http://wikiwiki.jp/neptune_v/?%A5%D1%A5%ED%A5%C7%A5%A3%B2%F2%C0%E2 (I don't see the legendary seven there though, but some of those people you listed are)

Comment: Looks like Megaman creator Keiji Inafune (Inafune Sword V), Xevious creator Masanobu Endo (Endo Drill), and the world's fastest button presser Takahashi Meijin's rival Mouri Meijin (Mouri Lance).